# TV episode with characters similar to the Smash Martians

Tags: story-identification, tv, robots

I am trying to identify a TV show I watched as a child in the UK. It is rather obscure.

The show aired on the ITV network in the late 1970's, I would guess between 1978 to 1973 and definitely shown on a week day afternoon as I recall watching it after school.

It may have been a one off TV special or a very short run of episodes and I only caught the final one because I clearly remember tuning in the follow week and being disappointed it was not being broadcast.

Regarding the show itself, it was a mix of puppets and live action. If memory serves (but it is rather blurry) the main characters were a group of robots or aliens reminiscent of and puppeteered in the same manner as the Smash Martians. For those who don't know, Smash was a brand of instant mashed potatoes and was advertised by puppets meant to be martians. Here is a link to one advert on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9d3qB7-7Fqg). I can be sure it was not simply an advert I watched as it was around 25 minutes long. A fairly standard length for a UK children's TV show.

Plot... I cannot recall many details sadly except that one scene involved the hero group of puppets being caught and imprisoned and another with a character who I think was simply a metallic ball with black eyes glued on teleporting into various places in search of something. At one point it surprises a woman in the bath who throws soap suds at it and screams.

It is possible I am conflating one or two different shows, the Children's Film Foundation film "The Glitterball" may account for some scenes but not all.

Comment: @TheBeardyMan Not a dupe, no accepted answer this side and the other answer is different to the one suggested here.

Comment: @TheBeardyMan thank you, I think it is very likely to be Stainless Steel and the Star Spies. I checked out the  question you mentioned and although it doesn't jog too many memories everything I read about this tallies with what i mention, particularly that it was a one off pilot episode that did not lead to a show. Can you upgrade your comment to an answer please.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Could this have been *[Button Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Button_Moon)*? Note in particular the character of Mr Spoon, the left most figure in the following picture:

[image]

Compared to a Smash Martian:

[image]

From the wikpedia article:

> Button Moon is a British children's television programme broadcast in
>   the United Kingdom in the 1980s on the ITV network. Thames Television
>   produced each episode, which lasted ten minutes and featured the
>   adventures of Mr. Spoon who, in each episode, travels to Button Moon
>   in his homemade rocket ship. All the characters are based on kitchen
>   utensils, as well as many of the props.
>
> Once on Button Moon, which hangs in "blanket sky", they have an
>   adventure, and look through Mr. Spoon's telescope at someone else such
>   as the Hare and the Tortoise, before heading back to their home on
>   'Junk Planet'. Episodes also include Mr. Spoon's wife Mrs. Spoon,
>   their daughter, Tina Tea-Spoon and her friend Eggbert. The series
>   ended in 1988 after 91 episodes.

Comment: No this one sadly, I remember Button Moon well so we can rule this out but thanks  for the suggestion.